# MySQL replication - rapidly growing relay bin logs

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-replication

Morning all,

I've got a really strange situation here this morning much like a reportedly fixed MySQL bug.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28421

My relay bin logs are rapidly filling with an infinite loop of junk made of this sort of thing.

```
#121018  5:40:04 server id 101  end_log_pos 15598207
#Append_block: file_id: 2244  block_len: 8192
# at 15598352
#121018  5:40:04 server id 101  end_log_pos 15606422
#Append_block: file_id: 2244  block_len: 8192
# at 15606567

...

# at 7163731
#121018  5:38:39 server id 101  end_log_pos 7171801
#Append_block: file_id: 2243  block_len: 8192
WARNING: Ignoring Append_block as there is no Create_file event for file_id: 2243
# at 7171946
#121018  5:38:39 server id 101  end_log_pos 7180016
#Append_block: file_id: 2243  block_len: 8192
WARNING: Ignoring Append_block as there is no Create_file event for file_id: 2243
```

These log files grow to 1Gb within about a minute before rotating and starting again.

These big files are interspersed with 1 or 2 smaller files with just this in

```
/*!40019 SET @@session.max_insert_delayed_threads=0*/;
/*!50003 SET @OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE=@@COMPLETION_TYPE,COMPLETION_TYPE=0*/;
DELIMITER /*!*/;
# at 4
#121023  9:43:05 server id 100  end_log_pos 106         Start: binlog v 4, server v 5.1.61-log created 121023  9:43:05
BINLOG '
mViGUA9kAAAAZgAAAGoAAAAAAAQANS4xLjYxLWxvZwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEzgNAAgAEgAEBAQEEgAAUwAEGggAAAAICAgC
'/*!*/;
# at 106
#121023  9:43:05 server id 100  end_log_pos 156         Rotate to mysqld-relay-bin.000003  pos: 4
DELIMITER ;
# End of log file
ROLLBACK /* added by mysqlbinlog */;
/*!50003 SET COMPLETION_TYPE=@OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE*/;
```

We're running a master-master replication setup with the problematic server running mysql 5.1.61. The other server which is, for the moment, stable is running 5.1.58.

**Has anyone got any ideas what the solution is to this and moreover, what might have caused this?**

Comment: By any chance, have you been running the `LOAD DATA INFILE` command  on the Master ???

Comment: Potentially! The master receives a number of SSIS packages on a regular basis and I'm not 100% familiar with how they load their data in. Is there a known problem with that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a good couple of hours of frantic searching, purging, resetting, etc... It seems that a good old fashioned turn it off and back on again is a solution.  Not quite a power cycle but a complete reset of slaves + masters.

```
slave stop;
reset master;
reset slave;
slave start;
```

I did this on each of the master/slaves such that all slaves were stopped before each of the masters were reset before restarting each of the slaves.

I hope that this helps someone else, there's not much out there on this situation.